# Seting maxlength of text field

Tags: jquery

We can use the following line to update  all input with attribute `maxlength="100"`

```
$("input").attr("maxlength", 100);
```

What I wish to achieve is to change the input of `type="text"` with maxlength unset to `maxlength=100`, is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: set the length to 0 or null.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [function version of `.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr) to look at the existing `maxlength` attribute of all `input type="text"` fields and only supply a new value if the old value is "falsey":

```
$('input:text').attr('maxlength', function(_, val) {
    return val ? val : 100;     // or return val || 100
});
```

Comment: Would `return val || 100;` have the same result?

Comment: Yes, it would, albeit it's a bit terser for newbies.

Answer (score 0):

Your want this using the [:text Selector](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/)

```
$("input:text").filter(function (index) {
    return $(this).attr('maxlength') === 'undefined';
}).attr("maxlength", 100);
```

Comment: this will overwrite any existing values.

Comment: @Alnitak: How about this one?

Comment: not portable to older versions of jQuery which AFAICR returned an empty string instead of `undefined` for missing attributes.  And you broke it by comparing with the string `"undefined"`, which is only OK if you used `typeof`.

Comment: and also it doesn't look efficient since internally it uses at least two loops - one to find the elements, and another to set the ones that need changing.

Answer (score 0):

Set of the attribute:

```
$("input:text").attr("maxlength", 100);
```

Remove of the attribute:

```
$("input:text").removeAttr("maxlength");
```